# Cannot find local directories in the Tex Live directory structure

Tags: texlive, installing, directory

I am dealing with a vanilla installation of Tex Live 2016 and with a Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. For the installation I lauched a `sudo install-tl` along the lines of [the instructions on www.tug.org](https://www.tug.org/texlive/doc/texlive-en/texlive-en.html#x1-140003). On the whole this has been successful, since I can launch `tex`, `xdvi`, `dvips` and so forth on the example documents.

However, in my installation settings, I had chosen the following directories

```
TEXMFCONFIG: "~/.texlive2016/texmf-config"  
TEXMFHOME: "~/texmf"
TEXMFLOCAL: "/opt/texlive/texmf-local"
TEXMFSYSCONFIG: "/opt/texlive/2016/texmf-config"
TEXMFSYSVAR: "/opt/texlive/2016/texmf-var"
TEXMFVAR: "~/.texlive2016/texmf-var"
```

and yet I can't seem to find any of the directories that had to be placed under `~` (say, with `cd && ls -a`). These are `TEXMFCONFIG`, `TEXMFHOME`, and `TEXMFVAR`

Is this a flaw of the installation procedure or am I supposed to create those directories manually?

In case this is relevant, I also noted in the log file of `install-tl` (pasted [here](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/23735060/)) that my chosen home directory had been reset in two cases

```
updmap [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /home/user) to root's actual home (/root).  # line 1128
fmtutil [WARNING]: resetting $HOME value (was /home/user) to root's actual home (/root).   # line 1324
```

Comment: you do not need the directories at all: the paths are just set up to make it convenient _if_ you need a local tex tree